# Date verification ignored

Tags: javascript

so I'm having a problem with my .js, basically it doesn't work and i have no idea why.

```
else {
    var dateOfBirth = new Date(formObject.dateOfBirth);
    var timestamp = new Date(formObject.timestamp);
    var timestampMonth = timestamp.getMonth();
    var dateOfBirthMonth = dateOfBirth.getMonth();
    var timestampYear = timestamp.getFullYear();
    var dateOfBirthYear = dateOfBirth.getFullYear();
    if (((timestampYear - dateOfBirthYear) === 1) && (timestampMonth === (dateOfBirthMonth -1))) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Błąd!',
        text: 'LAZY PO',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Close'
      });
    } else {
      google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Udało się!',
        text: 'Dane zostały przekazane do działu DELIVERY SUPPORT.',
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Close'
      });
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
  }
```

Script should check if date input by user in my form is later than 1 month from now.
If it is - an error should appear:

```
Swal.fire({
        title: 'Błąd!',
        text: 'LAZY PO',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Close'
      });
```

But it seems like the script is ignoring the date and accepts basically anything...

Comment: Have you took a look at DevTools' console?

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to be wrong, no errors are generated. This verification part is just ignored and script proceeds as "success" instead of showing an error.

Comment: The described expected behaviour and the given code have obvious mismatches. If you want to check whether it's the current year, you must check if the years subtracted equals `0` rather than `1`. Also, when you want to check if the dateOfBirthMonth is one month ahead, you need to **add** 1 rather than subracting 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate a function to calculate difference between dates.

In my opinion, the easiest way is to calculate the time in millisecond you want and check if the difference between those two dates match.

Here is an example of implementation.

```js
const ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISEC = 1000*60*60*24*31

function checkDateOneMonth(date1, date2) {
    return ONE_MONTH_IN_MILLISEC > Math.abs(new Date(date1) - new Date(date2))
}

console.log(checkDateOneMonth('2023-01-01','2022-12-15')) // true
console.log(checkDateOneMonth('2023-01-01','2023-02-10')) // false
```

---

*Note : Here the difference is based on 31-days months.*